# Spring Data Solr Facet Range example?

Tags: spring, solr, range, facet, faceted-search

Using Spring data solr 1.4 -- I have `FacetQuery` defined as such:

```
@Facet(fields = { "client", "state", “market”, “price"  }, limit = 10)
FacetPage<SearchResponse> findTerm(String fieldName, String fieldValue, String filterField, String filterValue, Pageable pageable);
```

How do I add ranges to the facet price? I don't want all the single values, but 10-20, 20-30, 30-40, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems still an open issue. Check:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr/pull/29

Comment: Now available in spring-data-solr 1.5.0-RELEASE http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.faceting.range

Comment: Mittal, I can't see facetRange example combining with Pivot? Does Spring support this?